# socket.io works only on one react-native components?

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I've a react-native project with some components. Now, I've a navigation helper with this code:

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Login: {screen: Login},
SinglePage: {screen: SinglePageChat},
Home: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        Home: {screen: ChatHome},
        ChatPage: {screen: ChatPage},
        Settings: {screen: Settings},
    }, {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "#eff0f1",
                borderTopWidth: 1,
                borderTopColor: "#D3D3D3"
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "red"
            }
        },
        lazy: false,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    })
}

},  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    headerMode: 'float', // screen for Android
});
// below options foreach page and the export default
```

As you can see my main page is the Login . Now, user goes to login, here I check if he has a token, then if yes I redirect him to Home screen. Here I connect the user to my socket.io and it works.

I've also a page that is called "SinglePageChat" where users can chat. Now I've a problem. Take as an example this code below:

```js
// in constructor
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://217.***.***.***:3000'); // this is the connection to the socket
// the code below is in the componentDidMount()
this.socket.on('hasMessages', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
});
```

it will not work. But in the ChatHome or in the ChatPage the socket works perfectly. Now, I need this code in the SinglePageChat component.

Why does not it work on that page? Something about navigator? I can not understand why it does so, I hope I was clear enough to explain my problem! If you need more code example, let me know!

Comment: Your socket.io server should be running on the same domain and port as the page is being served on, otherwise you'll run into cross origin restrictions

Comment: It works, when I load ChatHome I do that: `this.socket.emit('register', {connection_id: js.info.id});` and it works..

Comment: Then whatever your problem is likely isn't related to what you've shared. Does your server actually emit `hasMessages` to sockets that haven't emitted a `register` event? Maybe you thought that socket connections persisted across page navigation? They don't. When you go to a new page, you connect with a new socket, and as far as the server is aware it's a completely different client than the one that was connected from the previous page. You have to send the `register` event each time you navigate pages, if that's what the server is expecting.

Comment: Thank you, it was the problem. I was thinking that connection persists when I switch the page..!